# Why three wires?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, multiway-switch

I have a carport light that takes two switches to operate. An inside switch essentially sends power to an outside switch. In other words, when the inside switch is in the "on" position, the outside switch will turn the carport light on and off. But if the inside switch is in the "off" position, flipping the outside switch has no effect.

I decided to replace the outside switch (because it has been painted repeatedly and sticks) with a single pole switch. But when I took out the old switch, I found that it had 3 lines inserted into it, two black on one side, and one white on the other. Why are there three lines?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all switch boxes involved please?

Comment: What are the colors of the screws on the switch? What other wires are in the box, and how are they grouped into cables?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like someone cheated by removing a multi-way switch and replaced it with a single pole switch.

Normally a multi-way switch has a hot, a load and two travellers. One of the travellers is always hot. If both switches are on the same hot, the circuit is completed.

The trick here is you can use a three-way switch as a normal switch. You might have bought a dimmer switch at some point that came with more wires than you needed and were told to only use two specific wires or terminals. That's a three-way pretending to be a two-way.

The inside box likely has the line (from the circuit breaker), the load (to the lights) and the 3-line to the outside switch. The incoming line hot and the 3-line black attach to this switch. One of the returning travelers is hooked to the load. Your neutrals will be nutted together here, and the unused traveler (typically white or red) will be nutted off my itself. If this is the case, you can use a second multi-way switch here and attach the load to the black screw of the new switch, uncap the unused traveler and hook them to the brass screws. In this case, both switches will operate the lights then.

Answer (score 2):

this is what Ameicans call a three way switch (and eveyone else calls two way switching)

How it works is the inside switch selects one of two wires to send current down
and the outside switch selects one of the same two wires to accept current from. When the two switches are in agreement current flows and the bulb lights.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_switching#Traveler_system

Comment: Specifically, this is consistent with a three way switch where one of the wires in-between is disconnected. I bet if you reseat the light switch connectors, it'll turn into a three way switch.

Comment: or it could be that somebody replaced the inside with the wrong type.